# Mongo Elasticsearch Sink Connector doesn't work when I use "output.json.formatter" in my kafka source connector configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I'm working on Elasticsearch-mongo sync connectors using Mongodb kafka source connector and sync connector.

Here is my source connector configuration

```
name=mongo-source-connector11
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
tasks.max=1

#output.format.value=schema


# Connection and source configuration
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false 
connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017
database=localdb
collection=abcd
pipeline : [{'$match': { $or: [ { 'operationType': 'insert' }, { 'operationType': 'update' }, { 'operationType': 'delete' }, { 'operationType': 'replace' }, { 'operationType': 'rename' } ] } }]
poll.max.batch.size=1000
poll.await.time.ms=1000

output.schema.infer.value=true

output.format.key=schema
output.schema.key={\"name\":\"ClassroomId\",\"type\":\"record\",\"namespace\":\"com.mongoexchange.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"documentKey._id\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}

change.stream.full.document=updateLookup
copy.existing=true
```

Here is my elasticsearch sink connector configuration

```
name=elasticsearch-sink-connector11
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1

topics=localdb.abcd
connection.url=http://localhost:9200
topic.index.map=localdb.abcd:localdb
type.name="_doc"
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.ignore=false
```

This was working fine but in Elasticsearch Long Data type fields were coming like this:-

```
"someLongField" : 
          {
              "$numberLong" : "1006"
          }
```

but I want output to look like this:-

```
"someLongField": 1006
```

so in my kafka source connector configurtion, I added

```
output.json.formatter=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.json.formatter.SimplifiedJson
```

like it is mentioned [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongo-db-connector-for-apache-kafka-1-3-available-now)

After adding this My source connector is working and I'm a able see the expected output in "kafka-console-consumer.bat" but my sink connector is not working it not sending data to Elasticsearch.

Can someone please suggest some solution so that I get SimplifiesJson(i.e. without "$numberLong", "$numberInteger" ) in Elasticsearch.

**EDIT**
Here are the logs which I'm getting for ElasticsearchSinkConnector Failure

```
[2021-09-06 17:40:35,085] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-connector1111-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: Indexing record failed. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:607)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Indexing record failed.
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.handleMalformedDocResponse(ElasticsearchClient.java:455)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.handleResponse(ElasticsearchClient.java:400)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.access$200(ElasticsearchClient.java:65)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient$1.afterBulk(ElasticsearchClient.java:326)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestHandler$1.onResponse(BulkRequestHandler.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestHandler$1.onResponse(BulkRequestHandler.java:62)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.Retry$RetryHandler.finishHim(Retry.java:167)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.Retry$RetryHandler.onResponse(Retry.java:114)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.Retry$RetryHandler.onResponse(Retry.java:76)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient$1.onSuccess(RestHighLevelClient.java:1577)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$FailureTrackingResponseListener.onSuccess(RestClient.java:572)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:307)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:301)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:448)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:338)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=object mapping for [fullDocument.someLongField] tried to parse field [someLongField] as object, but found a concrete value]]
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:491)
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.fromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:402)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkItemResponse.fromXContent(BulkItemResponse.java:139)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkResponse.fromXContent(BulkResponse.java:199)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1706)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.lambda$performRequestAsyncAndParseEntity$10(RestHighLevelClient.java:1499)
    ... 19 more
[2021-09-06 17:40:35,090] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=elasticsearch-sink-connector1111-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:184)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:609)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:182)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:231)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Indexing record failed.
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.handleMalformedDocResponse(ElasticsearchClient.java:455)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.handleResponse(ElasticsearchClient.java:400)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.access$200(ElasticsearchClient.java:65)
    at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient$1.afterBulk(ElasticsearchClient.java:326)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestHandler$1.onResponse(BulkRequestHandler.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestHandler$1.onResponse(BulkRequestHandler.java:62)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.Retry$RetryHandler.finishHim(Retry.java:167)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.Retry$RetryHandler.onResponse(Retry.java:114)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.Retry$RetryHandler.onResponse(Retry.java:76)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient$1.onSuccess(RestHighLevelClient.java:1577)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$FailureTrackingResponseListener.onSuccess(RestClient.java:572)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:307)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:301)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:448)
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:338)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=object mapping for [fullDocument.someLongField] tried to parse field [someLongField] as object, but found a concrete value]]
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.innerFromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:491)
    at org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException.fromXContent(ElasticsearchException.java:402)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkItemResponse.fromXContent(BulkItemResponse.java:139)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkResponse.fromXContent(BulkResponse.java:199)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1706)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.lambda$performRequestAsyncAndParseEntity$10(RestHighLevelClient.java:1499)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Please clarify "not working". If the source is working and you're able to consume the topic, then the sink is maybe throwing some sort of error and you should include the logs in your question. Also, reduce your question with an [edit] to a [mcve] with just one JSON record copied from the source connector and focus your post on the Elastic one alone, assuming the Mongo one outputs the format you expect

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the suggestion, I have added the logs now. by "not working" mean that data is not going on Elasticsearch. As we can see in logs that because of some error, it is not going on elasticsearch

Comment: Have you tried manually defining an elasticsearch schema for your data? Or did you manage to delete the first index/schema created before you modified the output formatter setting?